# Extract Audio Duration from a drive folder in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, audio

I want to extract the exact audio duration uploaded on Google Drive, This code is already linked to Google Drive, have already tried adding getTime, getduration, ... but nothing seems to work, Please help

Is extracting duration from an audio file even possible in Google AppScript, If not then is there any other API that can help me out. ?

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {
var interactive = (typeof folderName === 'undefined');
if (interactive) {
folderName = Browser.inputBox("List files in folder", "Enter folder name", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
}

if (folderName === '') return;
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);

if (!folders.hasNext()) {
if (interactive) Browser.msgBox("Folder not found.");
return;
}

var folder = folders.next();
var contents = folder.getFiles();
var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();
sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "Time","URL", /*"Download",*/ "Description", "Type"]);
while (contents.hasNext()) {
file = contents.next();

if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) { // "SPREADSHEET"
continue;
}

data = [
file.getName(),
file.getDateCreated(),
file.getSize(),
file.duration(),
file.getUrl(),
file.getDescription(),
];

sheet.appendRow(data);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no duration method for Class File.  You can't just make up methods.  They have to exist in the class otherwise you're just wasting time.

Comment: You could load them into an html audio tag and possibly extract the audio duration that way and possibly store that information into developer meta data so that it could be looked up with file id.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*There is no official method to get the duration of an audio file with [DriveService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) or [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference).*

Currently the [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) resource only has metadata fields for images and videos. You can open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) for the implementation of an audio field for the files in Google Drive.